# Looping over spans and resetting / incrementing their text

Tags: jquery

I have a table with, lets say, 5 rows. In the first  element is a span with the row number.

```
<tr>
    <td><span name="rowNum">1</span></td>
    <td>...stuff...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><span name="rowNum">2</span></td>
    <td>...stuff...</td>
</tr>    
<tr>
    <td><span name="rowNum">3</span></td>
    <td>...stuff...</td>
</tr>    
<tr>
    <td><span name="rowNum">4</span></td>
    <td>...stuff...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><span name="rowNum">5</span></td>
    <td>...stuff...</td>
</tr>
```

However, I have a jquery function that may delete a table row.

I would like to add some code to the delete function that loops over the spans and resets the content to the correct row number.  E.g. if you delete the first row, span 2 will now say 1, etc.

I figure that I would set a counter = 1 to represent what the span value *should* be, then loop over the span, and if the span text is not = to the counter, then reset it.  The counter should then be incremented.

I'm just having trouble figuring how to loop over the spans and get their value.

Comment: You may be able to bypass this problem by using `<ol>` instead and styling the contents to look table-like.

Comment: unfortunately not, the snippet of code is a really simplified portion of a large table that can only work as a table. Thanks though!

Comment: @Blazemonger Using `ol` in a table?

Comment: I was thinking of something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/AxTmb/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After deleting a row you can change the text content of the spans using `text` method, it uses `each` method internally.

```
$('.rowNum span').text(function(index) {
   return ++index;
})
```

Comment: I ended up using `$('span[name="rowNum"]').text(function(index) {`

but overall, this worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS only, no JavaScript required: http://jsfiddle.net/brian_griffin/SNB89/

#### CSS

```
table { counter-reset: line-number;}
td:first-child:before {
content: counter(line-number) ".";
counter-increment: line-number;
padding-right: 0.3em; }
```

Or use `<OL>` (numbered list) as suggested above.